# Code for Reset Button in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, reset

I have a button called `Reset` in my iPhone application. It is for resetting purposes. I called `viewDidLoad()` method for this.  Is it right?

How to reset a page in iPhone?
how to write code for this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You should not call `-viewDidLoad` in your own code. It gets called on view controllers (VCs) when their view has just finished loading.

To return a VC to its original state depends largely on the specifics of the situation, but you could probably either set its properties and whatnot back to their original values or you could alloc and init a new VC, remove the old VC's view from the view hierarchy and add the new VC's view.

Alternately, you could just implement a `-resetToOriginalState` method on your VC.

Comment: Thanks Simon. But i haven t clear. -resetToOriginalState method is inbuilt method or we have to defined that? I have 4 buttons and 1 progressbar in my appln. i use timer for the progressbar. i stop that timer in resetAction().                                   -(IBAction) resetAction:(id)sender { NSLog(@"reset button clicked"); if(timer || [timer isValid]) { [timer invalidate]; timer= nil; } [self viewDidLoad];  i need some more help . thanks

Answer (score 0):

resetToOriginalState is not a inbuilt method, you have to write this method on your own and instead of calling viewDidLoad call this method 'resetToOriginalState:' when the respective button is clicked. If you are creating button programmatically you can set the target/action of that button like this:
resetBtn is the instance of the UIButton:

```
UIButton *resetBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,w,h)];

[resetBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(resetToOriginalState:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void)resetToOriginalState:(id)sender {
     //Do your stuff here 
}
```

If your using Interface Builder connect the action method (resetToOriginalState) to the button.